# How can I get the same format of output tables in R and Python?

Tags: python, r, csv, io

I have a sample csv as following:

```
x1, x2, x3
01, 02, 03
11, 22, 33
```

Reading it into R and `write.csv` generates:

```
"x1","x2","x3"
1,2,3
11,22,33
```

However, when I read it in `python` and try to write via `to_csv` here is what I get:

```
x1, x2, x3
1,2,3
11,22,33
```

I don't get the quotation marks in the header line of the output in `python`'s `to_csv`. In other words, what I want is the `csv` in earlier format but generated with `python`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's read your csv file correctly saying that data or headers can be separated by a `,` and possibly one or more spaces `\s+`

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=r',\s+', engine='python')
```

This gives us

```
   x1  x2  x3
0    1   2   3
1   11  22  33
```

Then we save to csv enforcing quoting non-numeric fields and drop the indexes
(see [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC))

```
df.to_csv("data_bis.csv", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

This gives

```
"x1","x2","x3"
1,2,3
11,22,33
```